# Convert an HVM ec2 instance into something that can be run on a PV instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, convert, virtualization, pv

I have a linux VM running on an esx-i server at home, and I would like to import the vmdk to aws using the [ec2-import-instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ImportInstance.html) command.

However I really don't need this to be any larger of an instance then an m1.small but because it's a linux image, the import command will only allow me to use [a type m3.xlarge or larger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html).

So is there another option?

Can I run the import to an m3.xlarge, create an snapshot / image, and use that image to launch a smaller instance? (would that just break all kinds of things?)

Or am I stuck trying to rebuild this machine from the ground up on aws?

Comment: Wow. That's...bizarre.